# Masstransit console application exits when consumer throws an exception

Tags: c#, .net-core, rabbitmq, masstransit

According to the docs: https://masstransit-project.com/usage/exceptions.html
It says the message is moved to an _error queue.
I have a console application which this behaviour is working as expected.
The problem is that when the consumer throws an exception, my console app crashes and closes.
Is this a bug? How to fix this? My app should not drop and keep running, correct?

```
public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<FileReceivedEvent> context)
     {
         var batch = context.Message;

         try
         {
             //code
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             //logging logic
             throw;
         }
     }
```

Comment: are you starting something on a separate thread. if yes, then it wont be caught by masstransit. see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23383538/exception-bubbling-in-masstransit-consumer-crashes-a-windows-service

Comment: Are you `await`-ing the `Task` correctly?

Comment: @JakubJankowski MT consumers are awaited by MassTransit.

Comment: The content of your console app initialization would greatly help.